# Difference results between Geocoding services and search on gMap

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I want to get the latitude and longitude for this adress : Boulevard de la Marne  Zone industrielle,  COULOMMIERS, 77120, France

I'm adding the api to my page with :

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true"></script>
```

When I use gmaps the result is good but when I want to retrieve it by the API :

```
 geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 geocoder.geocode({ 'address': myAdress, 'region': 'FR'}, function (results, status) {...});
```

It does the following request :

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?4sBoulevard%20de%20la%20Marne%20%20Zone%20industrielle%20%20COULOMMIERS%2077120%20&7sUS&9sfr-FR&callback=_xdc_._lsoj9s&token=53058
```

and the result is near Bamako...

If I use the viewport bounds it does the following request :

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?4sBoulevard%20de%20la%20Marne%20%20Zone%20industrielle%20%20COULOMMIERS%2077120%20&6m6&1m2&1d40.513799&2d-5.844727000000034&2m2&1d51.727028&2d10.854491999999936&7sUS&9sfr-FR&callback=_xdc_._c84svr&token=29019
```

It's better (it's in France) but it's not that

The query works well on the website google map :
https://maps.google.fr/maps?q=Boulevard+de+la+Marne++Zone+industrielle,++COULOMMIERS,+77120&hl=fr&ll=48.487486,3.922119&spn=1.541855,4.22699&sll=50.485474,25.620117&sspn=23.748757,67.631836&hq=Boulevard+de+la+Marne++Zone+industrielle,++COULOMMIERS,+77120&radius=15000&t=m&z=9

It seems that the only way to get it is by doing the following request :
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Boulevard%20de%20la%20Marne%20Zone%20industrielle,%20COULOMMIERS,%2077120&components=country:FR&sensor=false

I don't understand why the result are different when I use the viewport and not the country (the two results are in the bounds of the viewport)

Comment: Google Maps is more an implementation of the places-service than geocoding, so you may consider to request the places-service as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boulevard de la Marne Zone industrielle, COULOMMIERS, 77120, France is not an address, it is a "place".

The geocoder finds the location of Via De La Marne from that input:

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=Boulevard de la Marne Zone industrielle, COULOMMIERS, 77120, France&geocode=1

```
Found 1 results for Boulevard de la Marne Zone industrielle, COULOMMIERS, 77120, France
[ 0 ]: Av De La Marne, Bamako, Mali (12.6417952, -7.988396299999977)
```

The first result from the Places API looks more correct:

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=Boulevard de la Marne Zone industrielle, COULOMMIERS, 77120, France&place=1

```
Found 20 results for Boulevard de la Marne Zone industrielle, COULOMMIERS, 77120, France
[ 0 ]: Zone Industrielle, Boulevard de la Marne, Coulommiers, France (48.804329, 3.0923729999999523)
[ 1 ]: Boulevard de la Marne, Coulommiers, France (48.803048, 3.092110000000048)
[ 2 ]: 21 Boulevard de la Marne, Coulommiers, France (48.806634, 3.0937430000000177)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things are at play here.

"Boulevard de la Marne Zone industrielle, COULOMMIERS, 77120, France" is not recognized as an address by the Geocoding API because of the "Zone industrielle" part. If you remove that part, it works just fine:

[Boulevard de la Marne, COULOMMIERS, 77120, France](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DBoulevard%2520de%2520la%2520Marne%252C%2520COULOMMIERS%252C%252077120%252C%2520France)

Also, I found what looks like (a rare example of) an issue in Google Maps data, but I don't think fixing it would help with the above issue.

The place is found by Places API Text Search:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?radius=50000&location=0,0&query=Boulevard%20de%20la%20Marne%20Zone%20industrielle,%20COULOMMIERS,%2077120&key=YOUR_API_KEY

You'll notice that there is no `route` component in `address_components` when querying for Places Details by its place_id. This indicates that the place is not properly associated with the road.