# How can I make my Gmap geocoding request yields the same results as my direct search on Gmaps?

Tags: google-maps

If I query this url, I get no results :

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?region=GE&address=GT GROUP 48b Kakutsa Cholokashvili St, Tbilisi, 0113, GE&components=locality:Tbilisi|postal_code:0113|country:GE&sensor=false
```

Meanwhile, if I search for this adress on the google maps site (https://www.google.fr/maps/) it works:

```
 GT GROUP 48b Kakutsa Cholokashvili St, Tbilisi, 0113, GE
```

I read [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192571/difference-results-between-geocoding-services-and-search-on-gmap) that it has do with googlemaps using a different service than google geocoding.

How do I make my geocoding yields the same results as my direct search
 ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yup.  That is a [place](https://developers.google.com/places/) not an [address](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Geocoding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem to like the company name "GT GROUP" or the `postal_code=113` component, this url gives results:

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?region=GE&address=48b%20Kakutsa%20Cholokashvili%20St,%20Tbilisi,%200113,%20GE&components=locality:Tbilisi|country:GE&sensor=false`